# Get each object within depth object

Tags: java, recursion, collections, java-8, depth

I have this Person object. Each person have list of person object and so on, and it can be deep down infinite

```
    public class Person {

        private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

        public Person() {
        }

        ...

        public List<Person> getPeople() {
            return people;
        }

        public void setPeople(List<Person> people) {
            this.people = people;
        }

        public int maxDepth() {
            int maxChildrenDepth = 0;
            for (Person prs: people) {
                maxChildrenDepth = Math.max(maxChildrenDepth, prs.maxDepth());
            }
            return 1 + maxChildrenDepth;
        }

        public static Set<Person> getPersonLevel(Person person, int depth) {
            Set<Person> ppl= new HashSet<>();
            if (depth > 0) {
                 person.getPeople().forEach(prs -> ppl.addAll(getPersonLevel(prs, depth - 1)));
    }
      return ppl;
    }
```

Questions 1: Method --> maxDepth does not work. In that image, correct maximum depth is 3 (please see circled), but that method is giving me value 4.

Questions 2: Depending on the maxDepth, I want to get all the person in the list. For example, if i pass person object with maxdept 3 and if I pass depth as 2, i should get all **person 1** and **person 2** and **NOT person 3** in the list from that chart. I tried the effort by writing that method --> **public static Set getPersonLevel(Person person, int depth)** but that does not work as it return empty set all the time.

Any help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: On maxDepth you return n+1

Question 2 could be done using recursion.

Comment: @Nathan what do u mean?

Comment: You do `return 1 + maxChildrenDepth;` ... If this is one too many, try not adding one to it.

Comment: @Nathan i did remove and it return 0 instead of 2 and does not add. About question 2, i tried but does not work

Comment: Oh man sorry, disregard what I said. On mobile app and didn't scroll enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method

```
    public int maxDepth() {
        int maxChildrenDepth = 0;
        for (Person prs: people) {
            maxChildrenDepth = Math.max(maxChildrenDepth, prs.maxDepth());
        }
        return 1 + maxChildrenDepth;
    }
```

it should be obvious that a single `Person` object, not having any element in its list, will already return a depth of `1` (one). So each additional level adds one and in your picture, you have four levels, so you get the result four.

Your method

```
public static Set<Person> getPersonLevel(Person person, int depth) {
    Set<Person> ppl= new HashSet<>();
    if (depth > 0) {
         person.getPeople().forEach(prs -> ppl.addAll(getPersonLevel(prs, depth - 1)));
    }
    return ppl;
}
```

is traversing the entire `Person` tree, through all levels, but at no point, it is actually adding any element to the `Set`. All it does, is an `addAll` using another result of this recursive method, but as long as no actual adding happens, the result is an empty set and using `addAll` with an empty set is again not adding any element.

The main obstacle is that you apparently do not want to include/count the `Person` instance you’re evaluating/calling the method on. I suggest to straight-forwardly make this behavior optional, so when traversing the tree you can direct the methods to always count the sub-elements. Then, you can offer additional methods with the default behavior of not counting the root element:

```
public class Person {
    private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

    public Person() {
    }
    public List<Person> getPeople() {
        return people;
    }
    public void setPeople(List<Person> people) {
        this.people = people;
    }

    public Stream<Person> people() {
        return people.stream();
    }

    public Stream<Person> peopleLevel(int depth, boolean includeThis) {
        if(depth<0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        if(depth==0) return includeThis? Stream.of(this): Stream.empty();
        Stream<Person> sub = people();
        if(depth > 1) sub = sub.flatMap(p -> p.peopleLevel(depth-1, true));
        return includeThis? Stream.concat(Stream.of(this), sub): sub;
    }

    public static Set<Person> getPersonLevel(Person person, int depth) {
        return person.peopleLevel(depth, false).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    public int maxDepth() {
        return maxDepth(false);
    }
    public int maxDepth(boolean includeThis) {
        int chDepth = people().mapToInt(p -> p.maxDepth(true)).max().orElse(0);
        if(includeThis) chDepth++;
        return chDepth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code as below:

```
public class Person {
        private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        private String name;
        public Person() {
        }
        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public List<Person> getPeople() {
            return people;
        }
        public void setPeople(List<Person> people) {
            this.people = people;
        }

        public int maxDepth() {
            if (people.isEmpty()) {
                return 0;
            }
            int maxChildrenDepth = 0;
            for (Person prs: people) {
                maxChildrenDepth = Math.max(maxChildrenDepth, prs.maxDepth());
            }
            return 1+maxChildrenDepth;
        }

       public static void getPersonLevel(Person person, int depth, Set<Person> ppl) {
            if (depth <= 0) {
                return;
            } else {
                for (Person prs : person.getPeople()) {
                    getPersonLevel(prs, depth - 1, ppl);
                }
            }
            ppl.addAll(person.getPeople());
       }

      //just for logging
       @Override
       public String toString() {
            return "Person [name=" + name + "]";
      }
}
```

Client code for Question1: p0 -> person 0

```
System.out.println(p0.maxDepth());
```

Client code for Question2:
p0 -> person 0

```
Set<Person> ppl= new HashSet<>();
int depth = 2;
System.out.println(p0.getPersonLevel(p0, depth, ppl));
```

Hope this will help.